# how can i build a 3-input OR gate using only 2-input NAND gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, nand

[image]How can i build the above circuit?I have to use the boolean algebra rules like de morgans law.I tried already to simplify the equation,but nothing correct yet

Comment: You're right, **you** have to use the Boolean algebra rules. We are not here to do your homework for you. If you want any help at all you need to show what you have done so far.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because homework with zero attempt at a solution

Comment: Sorry for not posting what i've done :p

Comment: If you've only got a pair of two-input NAND gates, then the answer is *No, you can't* unless having one input inverted is ok. Basically all you can do is lop off one gate from the schematic you've provided so either Z will be inverted of both X & Y will be inverted.

Comment: Odds are he means with "2-input NAND gates".

Comment: @apostolis450 Easiest way is to separate X + Y + Z into 2-input gates (X + Y) + Z.  2 ORs.  Replace each OR with NAND implementation.  Remove double inverter NANDs.

Comment: “3 gate OR gate” or “3 input OR gate”?

Comment: The question is not clear, the diagram is not clear. The relationship between the diagram and the question is not clear. Re-write the question to be clear (then chances are, now that everything is clear, you may solve it your self).

Comment: @richard you are right i didnt set the question right.I apologise.

Comment: @apostolis450 - Hi, I have "rolled-back" to the previous version (version 3) of your question, as removing that diagram makes the subsequent comments meaningless and could be considered as vandalism of the question (which isn't allowed). Thanks for posting your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally figured out that i had to add one more nand gate(red circle) to get the same truth table of a 3-input OR.The problem was that by not having one more nand there,i had   (x' * y')' which equals to x+y.I should have (x+y)' so with the extra nand i get it.Thanks for every comment!

[image: final circuit]

Comment: You used 6 NAND gates. How is this a solution to your problem which requires to use max. **2** NAND gates?

Comment: sorry if i was not conceivable but i meant nand gates with 2 inputs,not maximum 2 nand gates.

Comment: The best questions are those you answer yourself!